# Using Flask-Login to Authenticate Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: python, nginx, flask, nginx-reverse-proxy, flask-login

I am implementing a modified version of Duo Labs' [py_webauthn](https://github.com/duo-labs/py_webauthn) demo in order to add physical authentication to my website. The demo is built in Flask, and uses the `flask-login` library in conjunction with an SQLAlchemy database to store user data.

What I would ideally like is for the Flask app to act as an Nginx authenticator, such that a logged-in user is able to access other `proxy_pass`'ed services on the server.

I had originally attempted to implement the reverse proxies in Flask, but the only working solution I have found requires the Twisted framework (as services like Shellinabox require constant requests being made), which needs a entirely separate WSGI application to be set up—an unnecessary middleman that is difficult to integrate.

My ideal result would be for a user to initially access the server and be `proxy-pass`'ed to the Flask authentication server, then would be able to access several other reverse-proxied services through Nginx. I am still open to a Python reverse proxy, but have found that Nginx best suits my needs.

How should I go about integrating Flask and Nginx?

(The app.py file for the demo library is available [here](https://github.com/duo-labs/py_webauthn/blob/master/flask_demo/app.py). The Webauthn functionality is simply built on top of `flask-login`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it! It is possible to use the builtin Nginx `auth_request` with Flask as an authenticator. Simply, if Flask returns a `200` upon being queried by Nginx, Nginx will then allow another page to be accessed. Alternatively, an error `401` can be returned by the authenticator to send the user to the Nginx 401 page (which, in my case, then redirects them to the login page).

To replicate, add an authenticator in Flask:

```
@app.route("/auth")
def nginx_auth():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return "You are logged in! Sweet!"
    else:
        return 'Sorry, but unfortunately you\'re not logged in.', 401
```

Then, in Nginx, point an `auth_request` to the authenticator, and redirect 401 to the login page.

```
location /ssh {
   auth_request /auth;
   proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/;
}

location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass              https://localhost:8081/auth;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}

error_page 401 = @error401;
location @error401 {
    return 302 /login;
}
```

(Code modified from [Nginx documentation.](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/))

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (authentication in my flask app results 404 when I redirect) and got here looking for an answer. My fix ended up being simpler.

In `nginx.conf` I set `proxy_set_header Host $host;` to `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`. I am still figuring out why it worked. I'll update the answer if I do.